# R and igraph: Creating a plot showing which kind of vertex attributes have edges between them

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

So I have got the following problem: I have got a rather large network which contains information about the personal connection between people. One of the vertex attributes is their town of residence. I now want to see if there is a connection between people from different towns. The kind of result I would like to get is a plot which represents these linkages. It might be the easiest to show an example of what I was looking for:

[image: Example image]

So in this case, the x-axis would represent the people from different towns, whereas the y-axis represents their friendship. So if a person from New York is friends with a person from Tokyo, a dot would be drawn at [New York, Tokyo]. This would be able tp give me additional information on top of the assortativity coefficient.

I have seen similar representations before in articles, but I am completely clueless how to create them using igraph on R. I was looking at the neighbors or neighborhood commands, but I haven't been able to figure out how to create something like this yet. Help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: Sample code that could be used to reproduce:

`g <- erdos.renyi.game(25, 1/10)`
`V(g)$location <- c("NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin")`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that can be used to test possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess you could just use a random sample graph like this:  
`g <- erdos.renyi.game(25, 1/10)`  

`V(g)$location <- c("NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin", "Berlin", "NY", "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Berlin")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you could do using `as_long_data_frame`:

```
df<- apply(as_long_data_frame(g),2,as.character)
colnames(df) <- c("from","to","from_city","to_city")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
ggplot(df,aes(x=from_city,y=to_city))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1))
```

[image]